# Get severity of boost.log logger..?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

Suppose I have a simple boost.log `severity_logger` logger set up like this:

```
   logging::core::get()->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::debug);
   logging::add_common_attributes();
   src::severity_logger< logging::trivial::severity_level > logger;
```

How would I check the severity programmatically?
I.e. somethinig like `logger.getSeverity()`..?

I've sifted through the docs and other questions here on StackOverflow but just couldn't find what should be a straightforward API call..?

Answer (score 5):

I would say you cannot. The logging system is layered in three layers (see [Design overview](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/design.html) of the logging system).

- Your `severity_logger` is a source logger with attribute `severity_level` within the data collection layer.
- The severity you set with `logging::core::get()->set_filter(...)` is a function object, that set for the logging core. All messages passed to a logger will get filtered by that function object, before being passed to the sinks.

So, there is actually no such thing as `severity` is the `severity_logger`. The severity is just passed to the core and then to the sinks.

---

EDIT: Elaborating on my comment, you could also declare a variable `severityLevel` and pass it to the `set_filter` function (using boost's reference wrapper `boost::ref()`)

```
// defined somewhere:
logging::trivial::severity_level severityLevel = logging::trivial::info;

// passed to set_filter() by reference
logging::core::get()->set_filter(
    logging::trivial::severity >= boost::ref(severityLevel));

// try out the logging:
BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, warning) << "A warning severity message"; // not filtered out
severityLevel = logging::trivial::error;
BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, warning) << "Another warning message"; // filtered out
```

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. So I'd have to store whatever is passed on to boost.log via `set_filter()` in my wrapper class

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. The filter function object could also be initialized with your own function which behavior could depend on some variable (see the class boost::logging::filter).